# Getting code from a text file and outputting into a table

Tags: php

I wonder if anybody can help me.

I have a text file that displays as so:-

### Name         Age Nat St Tk Ps Sh Ag KAb TAb PAb SAb Gam Sub  Min Mom Sav Con Ktk Kps Sht Gls Ass  DP Inj Sus Fit

D_de_Gea      26 esp 28  1  1  1 20 390 300 300 300  21   0 2033   1 178  16   0   0   0   0   0   4   0   0 100
A_Lindegaard  32 den 19  1  1  1 17 705 300 300 300   1   1   31   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 100

There are roughly 25 lines of this per text file.

I want to be able to display this in a table in HTML that will make it better to see than just creating a link to a notepad file.

I was wondering if anybody has any ideas that may be able to help me with this?

Thanks in advance.
Matt

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: this may be easier if you were to export that data to a `.csv` file, and use mysql and then iterate over those in a loop. Plus, being more manageable than using text files.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately these are updated twice a week so I won't be able to export them each time :(

Comment: Are they space delimited or tab delimited?  The function I'm thinking of will stuff them into an array, do you have a way to display an array as an HTML table?